# LaTeX Stretching the x-axis of the graph

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I asked this question on Reddit and they told me to come here. I'm wondering if there is a way to stretch my graph, because it is narrow horizontally.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c94KQ.png) is a picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{2130}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{scaledpicture}{10}(4,16)(-2,-7)
            \xaxis \yaxis \xnums{1} \ynums{2}
            \ticks{1} [-0.1] \thicklines
            \input{graph1}
        \end{scaledpicture}
        \caption {The graph $f(x) = x^3+3$}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `2130.sty` package: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b9d6f43cf1daf727334

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

If using another package is an option, I'd suggest you to use [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) to do your graphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
every axis plot/.append style={no marks,thick},
every axis/.style={
  axis lines=middle,
  width=5cm,
  height=7cm,
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot+[domain=-2:2] {(x*x*x)+3};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{the graph of $f(x)=x^{3}+3$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to used a different package but I will see

Comment: @hockeynl do you know if there's some documentation for `2130.sty`? I don't feel like going through the code.

Comment: @hockeynl and are you allowed to use `pgfplots`?